# Get Last Value that is not 'None'

Tags: sql, t-sql

All, I have a table with similar values to this:

```
Name    Value   Server time
a   None    3/17/2016 11:59:50 PM
a   None    3/17/2016 11:59:36 PM
a   None    3/17/2016 11:59:33 PM
a   March Madness   3/17/2016 11:59:33 PM
a   None    3/17/2016 11:59:19 PM
b   TGIF    3/17/2016 11:59:04 PM
b   None    3/17/2016 11:58:44 PM
b   March Madness   3/17/2016 11:58:29 PM
b   None    3/17/2016 11:58:22 PM
c   None    3/17/2016 11:58:17 PM
c   None    3/17/2016 11:58:15 PM
c   None    3/17/2016 11:58:14 PM
c   None    3/17/2016 11:57:50 PM
c   None    3/17/2016 11:57:33 PM
```

My result set should be this:

```
a   March Madness
b   TGIF
c   0
```

So in other words, I should get the latest value sorted by ServerTime that is not 'None' and when I just have 'None' it should be zero

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your rdbms ??  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: To expand on Juan's comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about "c", an easy way uses a `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.servertime = (select max(t2.server_time)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.name = t.name and t2.value <> 'None'
                     );
```

If you do want all names, then you can use an aggregation approach:

```
select name, max(case when t.value <> 'None' then servertime end),
       max(case when t.value <> 'None' and seqnum = 1 then value end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name
                                order by (case when t.value = 'None' then 1 else 2 end) desc,
                                         servertime desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by name;
```

Or even `outer apply`:

```
select n.name, t2.serertime, coalesce(t2.value, 0) as value
from (select distinct name from t) n outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.servertime, t2.value
      from t t2
      where t2.name = n.name and t2.value <> 'None'
      order by t2.servertime
     ) t2;
```

I actually like this  method.

Comment: Do you get `0` for `c` ?

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4ebfd5/30)**

Using just SQL you need create a list of every Name using distinct. Then join to find the MAX(sever time) for each name. Then a third join to get the value. Finally the NULL become `0` like the case for `c`

```
SELECT S."Name", 
       T.mtime, 
       CASE WHEN T.mtime IS NULL THEN '0'
                                 ELSE YT."Value"
       END as Value
FROM (
      SELECT  DISTINCT YT."Name"
      FROM YourTable YT
      ) S
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT "Name", MAX("Server time") as mtime
           FROM YourTable
           WHERE "Value" <> 'None'
           GROUP BY "Name"
           ) T
    ON S."Name" = T."Name"
LEFT JOIN  YourTable YT
   ON YT."Server time" = T.mtime
  AND YT."Value" <> 'None'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Name |                   mtime |         value |
|------|-------------------------|---------------|
|    a | March, 17 2016 23:59:33 | March Madness |
|    b | March, 17 2016 23:59:04 |          TGIF |
|    c |                  (null) |             0 |
```

Another solution with a less `JOIN`, create a dummy date to solve `C` case

```
SELECT TM."Name", 
       TM.mtime, 
       CASE WHEN T."Value" IS NULL THEN '0'
                                   ELSE T."Value"
       END as Value
FROM ( 
           SELECT "Name", MAX(CASE WHEN t."Value" <> 'None' THEN "Server time"
                                                            ELSE '0001-1-1 0:0:0'
                              END) as mtime
           FROM YourTable t          
           GROUP BY "Name"
      ) TM
LEFT JOIN YourTable T
  ON TM."Name" = T."Name"
 AND (TM.mtime = T."Server time" )
 AND T."Value" <> 'None'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, value  
from 
( select name, value 
       , row_number() over (partition by name, order by servertime desc) as rn 
    from table 
   where name <> 'None' 
) tt
where rn = 1 
union 
select name, '0' as 'value' 
from table 
where not exists (select 1 from table where name <> 'None')
```